# Caused by: org.elasticsearch.common.ParsingException: [bool] malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME]

Tags: elasticsearch

> Caused by: org.elasticsearch.common.ParsingException: [bool] malformed
>   query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME]

here is my request way :

```
    {
      "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
                "range": {
                    "timestamp": {
                        "gt": ${timestamp_from},
                        "lt": ${timestamp_to},
                        "include_lower": true,
                        "include_upper": false
                    }
                }
            }
          ]
        },
      "aggs": {
        "max_timestamp": {
        "max": {
        "field": "timestamp"
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query has several issues, and they are quickly discoverable when you look at some ES query examples.

- Root key should be `query`
- `aggs` key should go after `query`, not after `bool`
- ES has no idea what `${timestamp_from}` and `${timestamp_to}` are

So the correct query might be

```
{
   "query": {
      "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
                "range": {
                    "timestamp": {
                        "gt": 1409795880274,
                        "lt": 1509795880274,
                        "include_lower": true,
                        "include_upper": false
                    }
                }
            }
          ]
        }
},
      "aggs": {
        "max_timestamp": {
        "max": {
        "field": "timestamp"
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, i used ur solution , but i got a problem as same before. PS: my ES version is 5.6.3. i think the ES can not recognize this query's grammar.                   thanx a lot.

Comment: i got this problem when i use ur query [bool] malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME]

Comment: please help me sir